# Manipulations with corrplot

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I want to manipulate the plotting from the R package `corrplot`. With the following example from the package:

```
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)

cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95){
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):n){
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[,i], mat[,j], conf.level = conf.level)
      p.mat[i,j] <- p.mat[j,i] <- tmp$p.value
      lowCI.mat[i,j] <- lowCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
      uppCI.mat[i,j] <- uppCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
    }
  }
  return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}
res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars,0.95)
```

we can plot out the matrix with those statistically insignificant cells with a `X` sign:

```
corrplot(M, p.mat = res1[[1]], sig.level=0.05)
```

In addition, the confidence intervals can be shown with:

```
corrplot(M, low=res1[[2]], upp=res1[[3]], order="hclust",
              rect.col="navy", plotC="rect",cl.pos="n")
```

I'd like to combine the above two plots with the following manipulations:

1) Is it possible to paint the background of those statistically significant (instead of insignificant) cells with a color (e.g., deep blue)?

2) How to plot the lower triangular part of the matrix as 1) while using the upper triangular part to show the confidence intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your 2nd question, you could
plot the lower triangle:

```
corrplot(M, p.mat = res1[[1]], sig.level=0.05, 
        type='lower', tl.pos='lt')
```

and the upper one:

```
corrplot(M, low=res1[[2]], upp=res1[[3]], order="hclust",
        rect.col="navy", plotC="rect",cl.pos="n", 
        type='upper', tl.pos='n', add=T)
```

Regarding your 1st question, I'm not sure what you mean with background (I can't make comments yet - so I write here).

EDIT: One way to set the background color of each square according to its p-value is to give a matrix for bg. This works only for type="full". For a triangle part this has to be adjusted, otherwise the colors will be used from the part of the matrix that is not plotted.

```
sig_level = 0.05
bg_colors <- res1[[1]] < sig_level
bg_colors[bg_colors == T] <- "yellow"
bg_colors[bg_colors == F] <- "white"
diag(bg_colors) <- "white" # if the diagonal values shall be white

# select colors from lower/upper part of matrix:
bg_colors_lower <- bg_colors[lower.tri(bg_colors, diag=T)]
bg_colors_upper <- bg_colors[upper.tri(bg_colors, diag=T)]

# lower triangle
corrplot(M, p.mat = res1[[1]], sig.level=sig_level, 
         type='lower', tl.pos='lt', bg=bg_colors_lower)

# upper triangle
corrplot(M, low=res1[[2]], upp=res1[[3]], order="hclust",
         rect.col="navy", plotC="rect",cl.pos="n", 
         type='upper', tl.pos='n', add=T, bg=bg_colors_upper)
```

This gives:

[image: Corrplot with adjusted background color and mixed type]

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works well for the 2nd question! As for the 1st question, currently the default background is white for all the square cells (you can see that the unfilled part of each square is white). So, I would like to change the outside of the circle (within each square) to, for example, yellow for those cells that are statistically significant. Can this be done?

Comment: How to add background color to the upper part (confidence intervals)? I tried `corrplot(M, low=res1[[2]], upp=res1[[3]], order="hclust", rect.col="navy", plotC="rect",cl.pos="n", type='upper', tl.pos='n', bg=t(bg_colors), add=T)`, but the colored locations in the upper triangular part are not shown correctly.

Comment: The problem is that the full matrix has different dimensions than the plotted data, when using `type="lower"` or `type="upper"`. The color matrix/vector has to be adjusted as well. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I really appreciate it. Have a wonderful weekend!